# Customizing image uploading in TinyMCE

Tags: file-upload, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have an ASP.NET Web API web service which I want to use for file uploading. The way I do this is that the client posts a JSON object to the service at http://myserver.com/api/images/upload .

The object would contain a base64 string representation of the image, plus some metadata, e.g:

`{ companyId: 12345, image: "someBase64encodedStringRepresentingTheImage" }`

I would like to use TinyMCE on the client side, but I can't figure out how to customize it such that images are uploaded to the server in that format. (Actually, it doesn't seem like TinyMCE comes with an image uploader at all)

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE 4.2+ actually has its own built in process for handling the upload of images that you place in the editor:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

The basic process is that TinyMCE will create a separate HTTP POST for each image that you insert into the editor. It will send that image to a URL of your choosing (via HTTP POST) based on the setting of the `images_upload_url` option in your init.

The image handler at the URL referenced in the `images_upload_url` (which you have to create) has to do whatever needs to be done to "store" the image in your application. That could mean something like:

- Store the item in a folder on your web server
- Store the item in a database
- Store the item in an asset management system

...regardless of where you choose to store the image your image handler needs to return a single line of JSON telling TinyMCE the new location of the image. As referenced in the TinyMCE documentation this might look like:

```
{ location : '/uploaded/image/path/image.png' }
```

TinyMCE will then update the image's src attribute to the value you return. If you use the `images_upload_base_path setting` in the init that will be prepended to the returned location.

The net here is that TinyMCE knows when an embedded image exists in your content but it can't possibly know what to do with that image in the context of your application so that job (the "image handler") is something you must create.

There is an option for you to write your own image handler if the default one is not sufficient:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_handler

I would recommend trying to use the uploader that comes with TinyMCE so you don't have to write and maintain your own code going forward (always easier) but if the built in code is not appropriate you can indeed replace it with your own function.

Comment: I'm trying this, following everything on https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/, but I don't see the browse files button. Is there something else I'm missing? I've tried a few of the file managers, but they are for managing files on the server, and I don't want that. I only want to let users upload their local files, not mess with files that have been uploaded by others.

Comment: @AndyD273 Can you post some code on a TMCE Fiddle or Codepen type site?  Hard to say what might be wrong without seeing any code.

Comment: @AndyD273 perhaps you need to add a `file_browser_callback` function to your init so you have the option to browse the local file system?

Comment: That is probably what I'm missing, but I haven't seen any examples of what to put in a file_browser_callback other than one of the file managers that lets you manage files on the server, which isn't what I want. I have gotten a popup style window to open, but it didn't really do anything, like display a way to select a file to upload...   http://fiddle.tinymce.com/awfaab/1

Comment: @AndyD273 here is a page that provides one approach for this ... https://www.morethanweb.es/en/news/how-to-implement-a-file-loader-in-tinymce-4.html

Comment: That looks really promising. +1